# Перенос строк в переменной.

Tags: html, javascript

Почему не работает, когда переносишь строки?

```
var _wnd_content = '
<div id="abc">
 text
</div>
';
```

Comment: А должно ли?

Comment: Раз уж гугл сюда посылает при подобных вопросах, то я делаю так
\n\

Answer (score 10):

Потому что синтаксис такого не позволяет.

Варианты:

```
var _wnd_content = '\
  <div id="abc"> \
    text \
  </div>';
```

Используя массив:

```
var _wnd_content = [
    '<div id="abc">',
    '    text',
    '</div>'
].join("\n");
```

Как обычно делают шаблонизаторы:

```
<script type="text/x-my-template" id="template_abc">
    <div id="abc">
        text
    </div>
</script>

var _wnd_content = $("#template_abc").html();
```

Используя E4X (будет дерево, а не строка; и это не работает, как минимум, в IE):

```
var _wnd_content = <div id="abc">text</div>;
```

ECMAScript 6 (это как будет в светлом грядущем):

```
var _wnd_content = `
    <div id="abc">
        text
    </div>
`;
```